# How to Retrieve data from SharePoint list via PnP JS Core and CAML Query

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, caml-query, spfx-webparts, pnp-js-core

As I am new to SharePoint framework, I am using PnP JS core library in SharePoint webpart,please suggest how can I retrieve list items from SharePoint list via PnP JS core and CAML Query.

Please suggest any workaround for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get items from SharePoint list using a CAML Query.

**Sample Code**:

```
import { ICamlQuery } from "@pnp/sp/lists";

// build the caml query object (in this example, we include Title field and limit rows to 5)
const caml: ICamlQuery = {
    ViewXml: "<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields><RowLimit>5</RowLimit></View>",
};

// get list items
const r = await list.getItemsByCAMLQuery(caml);

// log resulting array to console
console.log(r);
```

**References**:

1. [Get list items using a CAML Query](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/lists/#get-list-items-using-a-caml-query)

Comment: how can we display the  retrieved line items

Comment: It is totally based on which framework you are using and how you want to design your UI.

Comment: I am using sharepoint wepart , how can loop the retrieved line items.... I using data.getEnumerator()...while this is not working..